# How can I add some selective features/ subfeatures to a new release build through Automation Interface

Tags: installshield, installshield-le, installscript

I am using Install Script in Install Shield 2013 on Windows 7, Lang Used C#.

I have a project and it has some features and sub features added to it. Now I want to build a new release using Automation Interface need to add some selective features/ subfeatures to this release so that the original features remains unaltered.

We can pass the New release name and features required in this release using Command Line.

**How can I add selective features supplied as command line arguments to my release. Is there any predefined Object/function/Method for this. Please advise.**

Need to achieve this in Install Script only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do so by using IncludeInBuild() property of ISWiFeature. It alters the default IncludeInBuild value of a feature.

To make it temp store the current values of the features to be altered in a list , then build a new release. After making new release, once again assign the value stored in list to the altered features.